# Reload a file upload in an edit page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP project.
In this project I have a list of drinks in an SQL database. Besides the list I have an "edit" link button that on an user click, it can change drink property, then in my edit page all of that drink data should be reloaded, and all they reload correctly except two:
1.picture,
2.the type of Drink (I use radio buttons here)
In this problem user must upload and set type of drink every time when entering to edit page.
What should I do?

```
    private void LoadData()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["uid"]);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", connection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select * from Drink where DrinkID=@id";
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        da.Fill(dt);
        TxtName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["DrinkName"].ToString();
        TxtDesc.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
        string DrinkPic = FileDrink.FileName;
        DrinkPic = dt.Rows[0]["DrinkPicture"].ToString();
        string kind;
        if (Rbwarm.Checked)
        {
            kind = Rbwarm.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            kind = Rbcool.Text;
        }
        kind = dt.Rows[0]["DrinkType"].ToString();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are probably doing wrong:

```
    string DrinkPic = FileDrink.FileName;
    DrinkPic = dt.Rows[0]["DrinkPicture"].ToString();
```

Here you are not changing the image file.
First, get the filename and then load the image. Somthing like:

```
    string DrinkPic = dt.Rows[0]["DrinkPicture"].ToString();
    DrinkImage.Image = Image.FromFile(DrinkPic);
```

And then the same for your radiobuttons. You are not changing their status.
It must be something like:

```
    string kind = dt.Rows[0]["DrinkType"].ToString();
    Rbwarm.Checked = kind == "Warm";
    Rbcool.Checked = kind == "Cool";
```

Comment: tnx, for your answer, I do it, like you for my picture but another way for radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

i Myself solve it too

```
       private void LoadData()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["uid"]);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", connection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select * from Drink where DrinkID=@id";
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        da.Fill(dt);
        TxtName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["DrinkName"].ToString();
        TxtDesc.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
        picname = dt.Rows[0]["DrinkPicture"].ToString();
        string kind = dt.Rows[0]["DrinkType"].ToString();
        if (kind == Rbwarm.Text)
        {
            Rbwarm.Checked=true;
        }
        else
            Rbcool.Checked=true;
        if (Rbwarm.Checked)
        {
            kind = Rbwarm.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            kind = Rbcool.Text;
        }

    }
```